# Stop iMac from sleeping when used as an external display

Tags: imac, macbook-pro, displayport

I have an iMac which I sometimes use as an external display for my Macbook Air. Normally, I want the iMac to go to sleep after about 30mins *except* when I have the Air attached.

Is there any app (or Applescript?) out there which will change/disable the sleep time when it's being used as a display, but still let the iMac sleep when the Air is not connected?

Comment: Wait, if you're using your iMac as an external display, won't it go to sleep only if your Air goes to sleep?

Comment: That's what I was hoping but it didn't seem to be the case yesterday when I was using it.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a very popular app called [caffeine](http://caffeine.en.softonic.com/mac) that sits an icon in your menu bar, and when you click it the app prevents your computer from sleeping either indefinitely or for a predetermined period of time.

Comment: Thanks. I already use Caffeine and it's a reasonable solution but I was hoping there would be something more automated